# React-Bootstrap radio input as button group with formik

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I'm trying to get a radio button to appear as a button group with buttons yes/no as a reusable react component using formik also..

```
const BooleanInput = (
  props: { label: string; size: number } & FieldHookConfig<string>
) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);

  console.log(`label: ${props.label} value: ${!!field.value}`)
  return (
    <Form.Group as={Col} md={props.size}>
      <Form.Label>{props.label}</Form.Label>
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <ToggleButtonGroup
          name={field.name}
          type='radio'
          value={field.value}
          size='sm'
          onChange={field.onChange}
          defaultValue={+!!field.value}
        >
          <ToggleButton
            id={field.name}
            variant='outline-secondary'
            value={1}
          >
            Yes
          </ToggleButton>
          <ToggleButton
            id={field.name}
            variant='outline-secondary'
            value={0}
          >
            No
          </ToggleButton>
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
      </ButtonToolbar>
    </Form.Group>
  );
};
```

The value passed from the formik field is a boolean, and the values are being set but the default value is being ignored and when I click a button I get a typescript error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type'). Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Worked this out in the end, there is some helper functions in useField hook which includes setValue, so instead of using field.onChange directly, you can do the following ..

```
<ToggleButtonGroup
  type='radio'
  value={+field.value}
  name={field.name}
  onChange={(option, action) => {
    helpers.setValue(option)
  }}
>
```